# .vb keeps giving 0 as total amount you need to pay

Tags: vb.net

So i had to make a program where you can buy stuff when clicking on the buttons, when the amount totals more than 1k you can roll for a discount. This all goes well until I have to use a label to indicate the total amount you need to pay minus the discount. This label keeps staying 0, no matter what. Could anyone help?

Form1 for the "shop":

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim totaalbedrag As Double
    Public Sub Actie()
        If Val(TextBox3.Text) > 1000 And i = 1 Then
            If MsgBox("Wil je strijden voor korting? Zo niet zal deze pop-up niet meer komen dus maak je keuze!", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            Else
                i = 0
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label6.Text = Val(Label6.Text) + 1
        TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + 250
        TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text)
        Actie()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Label7.Text = Val(Label7.Text) + 1
        TextBox2.Text = Val(TextBox2.Text) + 300
        TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text)
        Actie()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        TextBox4.Text = korting & " procent"
        totaalbedrag = totaalbedrag - totaalbedrag * korting / 100
        TextBox5.Text = Val(totaalbedrag)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        MsgBox("Gefeliciteerd met de aankoop van totaal " & totaalbedrag & " euro!!", vbCritical)
        End
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form2 for the gambling:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        korting = Label1.Text
        MsgBox("Gefeliciteerd, je hebt " & korting & " procent korting gekregen!", vbCritical)
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = Int(Rnd() * 10)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Module to have a value as a public one:

```
Module Module1
    Public korting As Integer = 0
End Module
```

You basically should pay attention to this code of line since I think this is where all goes wrong:

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        TextBox4.Text = korting & " procent"
        totaalbedrag = totaalbedrag - totaalbedrag * korting / 100
        TextBox5.Text = Val(totaalbedrag)
    End Sub
```

Comment: You have to be more precise . Which label are you talking about ?

Comment: If you set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and also set it as the default for new projects) and correct the problems it then shows you, it might start working.

Comment: Please stop using `Val()`. If the user enters 34,000 , Val will return 34! You can use `CDec()` but you should really validate any user input first with a `.TryParse()`

Comment: Don't use double, use decimal, don't use Val, use the appropriate TryParse, and finally use appropriate names, button1 and textbox5 aren't going to help you or anyone else figure out what is going on.  I would also suggest setting `Option Strict On`.  While not as important, and not everyone agrees, you might want to think about using English names.

Comment: Where is `korting` declared?

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all sure of the timer event in Form1. Every time it ticks the discount is reapplied. If the program runs long enouth totaalbedrag will be very small.

I used .ToString("C") or "c" to display the result as currency. Some of displays are probably not currency. Change to the appropriate format string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

For Random numbers please switch to the .net Random class.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim totaalbedrag As Decimal

    Public Sub Actie()
        Dim tb3Dec As Decimal
        If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, tb3Dec) AndAlso tb3Dec > 1000 AndAlso i = 1 Then
            If MsgBox("Do you want to compete for a discount? If not, this pop-up will not come again so make your choice!", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            Else
                i = 0
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        TextBox4.Text = korting & " procent"
        totaalbedrag = totaalbedrag - totaalbedrag * korting / 100
        TextBox5.Text = totaalbedrag.ToString("C")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tb1Dec As Decimal
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, tb1Dec) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in TextBox1.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim tb2Dec As Decimal
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, tb2Dec) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in TextBox2")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Label6.Text = (CDec(Label6.Text) + 1).ToString
        TextBox3.Text = (tb1Dec + tb2Dec).ToString("c")
        TextBox1.Text = (tb1Dec + 250).ToString("C")
        Actie()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Label7.Text = (CDec(Label7.Text) + 1).ToString("c")
        Dim tb2Dec As Decimal
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, tb2Dec) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in TextBox2")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim tb1Dec As Decimal
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, tb1Dec) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in TextBox1")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        TextBox2.Text = (tb2Dec + 300).ToString("C")
        TextBox3.Text = (tb1Dec + tb2Dec).ToString("C")
        Actie()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        MsgBox("Gefeliciteerd met de aankoop van totaal " & totaalbedrag & " euro!!", vbCritical)
        End
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Private rand As New Random

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        korting = CInt(Label1.Text)
        MsgBox("Gefeliciteerd, je hebt " & korting & " procent korting gekregen!", vbCritical)
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = rand.Next(0, 101).ToString 'returns an integer 0 to 100
    End Sub

End Class
```

This fixes the Option Strict violations but I have no idea it this works for you. Let us know which label is showing 0.